# How to customize ListView with ToggleButtons

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view, togglebutton

I am making an android application.I have ListView in it which contains four rows having textView i.e
Hide 
Unhide
Add Users
Delete users
I want to add ToggleButton in ListView for first two rows but don n't want to show it for other rows. How can i customize my ListView in this way.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If your intended design has only the four rows you've mentioned, there's really no reason to use a ListView for it, is there? I would think a combination of LinearLayouts would be sufficient.

Comment: its just an example Mike , wanna explain my query, let suppose i have multiple rows , how can i make customise some rows with toggle button , not whole ListView ???

Comment: Then you will need to implement a custom Adapter for the ListView, and vary the rows' layouts depending upon whichever criteria you need to check against. If you need more detailed information, you will have to be more explicit in your case description.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a custom [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). There you have the method `getView()` that is called for each `listItem`, so this is the right palce to define the layout of the `listItems`.

Please look at [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) to ensure a smooth scrolling of your list.

And you can find a good Tutorial on [Vogellas site](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add toggle button for first two rows only and not for all rows then one easy thing you can do is add in the custom listview layout file both the textview and toggle button but while implementing add (null) in the toggle button's place in the adapter for the rows for which you don't want the toggle button...

Comment: Can you kindly give an example code, where null have been passed for in adapter for some rows ??